# Losing control of PC mouse: it keeps pulling back to same spot

Tags: mouse, desktop-computer

I'm a non-expert PC user. I am using a Lenovo AIO 700-24ISH Ideacentre desktop PC. The OS is Windows 10 Home. There has not been physical damage to the PC before the fault. Windows Defence Security Centre does not report any known problems.

I have uploaded a video showing how the problem looks like on youtube at https://youtu.be/R8RIPdgAaVk.

I'd be grateful for any help and guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: thanks. yes. same problem with wireless or wired mice.

Answer (score 0):

Since disabling the touchscreen fixes it, it sounds like it's a hardware issue.

So aside from replairing/replacing the digitizer on the display (or replacing the display entirely), disabling it is the only thing that will make things better.

---

*Previously:*

Is that a touchscreen?  Or do you have some kind of other touch device attached to your system?

It looks like your system thinks someone is constantly touching that particular area of your display, which takes the cursor there.

Try disabling any additional input devices, trackpads, touchscreen ability, drawing tablets, etc. that you might have attached, and see if it still happens.

---

Sorry, I don't have enough rep in this site to post comments yet.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: yes it's a touchscreen

Answer (score 0):

I've been guided in other fora to this solution:

Disable the touchscreen.

(https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht502617)

I've done this, and it seems to have stopped the symptom. (Though I do wonder if there might be a lasting solution that does not involve disabling of the touch screen function per se?)